# Is clustering retained after an overwrite from the results of a query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

### My Question

When I run a scheduled query, will the results be clustered in the destination table I have configured? Does the behaviour change depend on if "append" or "overwrite" is used?

### Example

I have created an empty table ("destination table") with a schema where four fields are clustered (and I have one field for time partitioning but that may be irrelevant to my question).

I then run a scheduled query whose output has the identical schema as the destination table with "overwrite" set (via the UI for the scheduled query) with the destination table chosen as above.

The results are saved to the table - but I have no way to verify that the new data are actually clustered other than by checking the table details, which doesn't necessarily mean that all data in the table is clustered (see the part about altering tables in the documentation below).

### Documentation

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables):

> You can create a clustered table in the following ways:
>
> From query results:
>
> - By using a DDL CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement.
> - By running a query that creates a clustered destination table.
>
> By using a DDL CREATE TABLE statement with a CLUSTER BY clause containing
> a clustering_column_list.
>
> Manually by using the bq command-line tool
> bq mk command.
>
> Programmatically by calling the tables.insert API
> method.
>
> When you load data.
>
> By using the client libraries.

I suppose scheduled queries may be counting as load jobs but then, why distinguish them from "query results" (whose queries could, for example, be configured to overwrite or append to a destination table)?

The same [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#modifying-cluster-spec) describes that table definitions can be altered to include clustering but it only affects data added after the change i.e. I believe this may also include if I have an empty table and append or overwrite with new data.

Can anyone confirm the behaviour (or suggest some way to see **which data** in a table is actually clustered)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table specifications say that it use clustering than the data in the table is clustered. The question is more on the clusters "quality". Infact, when inserting data into a clustered table this could degradate the clustering balance resulting in higher scan. However, BigQuery performs [auto re-clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#automatic_re-clustering) in the background to improve this. This is done on a best effort basis and it is free.

Different is when "create or replace" a table (probably same thing of "overwrite"). When performing such operation the table created has already optimized clusters.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're saying that the scenario I describe should result in a table which is clustered (and clustered optimally)?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: In the absence of any other contrary indications, I'll accept it as the answer - thanks!